# Using columns of big.matrix in fisher.test in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-bigmemory

I have a very large binary big.matrix and also a vector of class assignment (same length as number of rows of big.matrix).

I want to be able to loop through each column of the big.matrix and output the p value for each fisher.test.

With a normal matrix object, I can do the following, but converting my big.matrix into a matrix takes up over 5 gb of ram.

```r
p.value <- unlist(
    lapply(
        lapply(as.data.table(binarymatrix),
               fisher.test,
               y = class
        ), function(x) x$p.value
    )
)
```

How can I do this without converting into a matrix object? As I understand it, accessing elements of a big.matrix requires C++ code, but I am not familiar with this at all.

Here it shows how to do fisher.test in Rcpp [Rcpp: Is there an implementation fisher.test() in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737308/rcpp-is-there-an-implementation-fisher-test-in-rcpp) but I am not sure how to input each column of a matrix into this.

An example big.matrix would look like

```
library(bigmemory)
matrix <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100 * 10000, replace = TRUE), 100 , 10000)
bigmatrix <- as.big.matrix(matrix)
```

And my class variable looks like:

```
class <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the Rcpp code I have right now. If someone could help me figure out the issue I would really appreciate it.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen, RcppArmadillo, bigmemory, BH)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <bigmemory/BigMatrix.h>
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
ListOf<IntegerVector> AccessVector(SEXP pBigMat, int j, vector<int> status) {
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);
  MatrixAccessor<int> macc(*xpMat);
  
  int n = xpMat->nrow();
  
  // Bigmemory
  cout << "Bigmemory:"; 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << macc[j][i] << ' ';
  }
  cout << endl;    
  
  // STD VECTOR
  vector<int> stdvec(macc[j], macc[j] + n); 

  // Obtain environment containing function
  Rcpp::Environment base("package:stats"); 
  
  // Make function callable from C++
  Rcpp::Function fisher_test = base["fisher.test"];    
  
  // Call the function and receive its list output
  Rcpp::List test_out = fisher_test(Rcpp::_["x"] = stdvec, Rcpp::_["y"] = status);
  
  // Return test object in list structure
  return test_out;
}
```

Ideally I want to be able to loop through each of the columns in C++ itself, and just output the p-values to R.

Comment: You can access the column of bigmatrix by index in R: `res <- vector('numeric', ncol(bigmatrix));
for(i in seq_along(res)){
    res[i] <- fisher.test(bigmatrix[, i], class)$p.value
}`. However, I am not sure whether this is fast enough for your real data.

Comment: This seems to increase ram usage significantly and also is taking a long time. Thanks for the suggestion though! Essentially what I was hoping to do is write a C++ function to take input from each column and process it in the Rcpp to speed it up hopefully, but with limited experience I reached out for help with that.

Comment: @mt1022 I added some Rcpp code, but I can't get it to work. If you could help me figure out the issue I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What you show is using `fisher.test` R function from Rcpp. This should not be faster than what @mt1022 propose. You need to find a true Rcpp function or a vectorized R function that can be used on a block of columns at a time, if you want a faster solution.

Comment: @F.Privé Is there a way to parallelize (as in run more than one column at a time) mt1022's solution without increasing memory usage significantly?

Comment: @F.Privé My ultimate goal is to keep RAM usage as low as possible while making computation decently fast, if not the fastest possible. I thought that running fisher.test through Rcpp might help with the RAM issue. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Nop it won't help you. This is why I propose to access blocks of colums. This is a good compromise between memory usage and speed if you have a vectorized (fast) function.